# How to position text to the left of something in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Right now I am able to get a group of text to the left of the screen, however it is underneath an image. How can I get it so that it is to the left of that image? Also, when I try aligning the text in CSS, it does not do anything. The way that I have positioned it so far is in HTML.

Here is what I have:

```css
   <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
       body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #pic{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
            width: 800px; height: 600px }

    .allQuestions {
      text-align: left; /* This doesnt do anything */
    }
  </style>
```

```html
        <div id="pic" ></div>

    <div id = "allQuestions" style="float: left;">

        <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('q1');">
          <h1 id="q1" data-original="Click A" data-after="You've clicked A" 
          data-toggled="0">Click A</h1></div>

        <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('q2');">
          <h1 id="q2" data-original="Click B" data-after="You've clicked B"
          data-toggled="0">Click B</h1></div>

        <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('q3');">
          <h1 id="q3" data-original="Click C" data-after="You've clicked C" 
          data-toggled="0">Click C</h1></div>

        <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('q4');">
          <h1 id="q4" data-original="Click D" data-after="You've clicked D"
          data-toggled="0">Click D</h1></div>

        <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('q5');">
          <h1 id="q5" data-original="Click E" data-after="You've clicked E" 
          data-toggled="0">Click E</h1></div>       

    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have:

[image: screenshot]

Wait, why is the screenshot not showing...?

Comment: Please make the code you include in the question such that it actually replicates the problem. With a real picture etc.

Comment: Do you want your text to be on your image?

Comment: @IVIajid No I do not. I still want my image to be in the center of the screen, like how it now, but I want the text to be to the left of it. That's it.

Comment: The image's position would not move, it would still be in the center, but the text would move to the left of the image.

Comment: What I meant is that you should include an actual image, currently you only have an empty `div`, and that is not an actual image. Therefore, the code does not replicate your problem. For future questions, check out e.g. http://lorempixel.com/ or something similar where you can grab a picture to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to float text to the left of an image.

Learn about the position css attribute here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Hope this helps!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="text-float">Some Cube</span>
    <img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { 
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 300px; 
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
}
.container img{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
.container span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:-90px;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6teet7gx/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<div id="allQuestions" style="float: left;">    
  ...a bunch of text/headers
</div>
<div id="myImg" style="float: right;"></div>
```